# How can I Join 2 tables with json array withot key postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables like:

**Person:**

```
name | providers_ids
-----|--------------
name1|"{1, 2}"
name2|"{3, 4}"
```

**Providers:**

```
id   | name
-----|--------------
1    | name_provider1
2    | name_provider2
3    | name_provider3
4    | name_provider4
```

I have to get the following result:

```
person.name | providers_ids
------------|--------------
name1       |name_provider1
name1       |name_provider2
name2       |name_provider3
name2       |name_provider4
```

I have to do this in postgres. I read that we can use `lateral join`, but I did not make it. The json array field type (provider_ids) is `varying[]`. I think that I have to convert to another type before join.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Did you mean to use array syntax (with `[]`)?

Comment: By `varying[]`, you mean `character varying[]`?

Answer (score 0):

If `person(provider_ids)` is a legitimate `jsonb` array, you can use [the `?` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
select pe.name person_name, pr.name provider_name
from person pe
inner join providers pr on pe.provider_ids ? pr.name
```

If `provider_ids` is not `jsonb` (maybe `json`), you would need to cast it first:

```
select pe.name person_name, pr.name provider_name
from person pe
inner join providers pr on pe.provider_ids::jsonb ? pr.name
```

---

Last option: if `provider_ids` is a postgres array, then you can use operator `any`:

```
select pe.name person_name, pr.name provider_name
from person pe
inner join providers pr on pr.name = any(pe.provider_ids)
```

Comment: The provider_ids type is varying[]. Is like a json string with numbers. Exactly like "{100, 1001, 200}". Is a string in json format.

Comment: Then I have to join with each id in this string

Comment: `?` selects object keys, not array values

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an array of strings, not actual JSON. In that case, you can use a [lateral join with `unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS):

```
SELECT person.name, providers.name as providers_ids
FROM person, unnest(person.providers_ids) as pp(id) JOIN providers USING (id)
```

([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=33595e072613af677024dd31617f56e1))